# Would it be possible to "teleport" energy?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, energy, teleportation

This is for a storyline that I have been building.

Currently, scientists are able to teleport spin cubits in laboratory conditions. This is often mentioned in connection with information transfer.

But I wanted to get some technical idea if it could be possible to transfer large amounts of energy (instead of information) through either teleportation machinery, wormholes, or some other quantum tunneling mechanism.

(My understanding is that energy conservation should not restrict this as in this scenario all of the energy would stay within this universe.)

Comment: [Pure energy doesn't exist](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9735/56299) (asked by a different HDE!); only matter exists.

Comment: Do you mean qubit (quantum bit) instead of cubit (length of forearm)?

Comment: http://phys.org/news/2014-01-theory-teleport-energy-distances.html

Comment: I hate to disappoint you but you cannot teleport energy or matter, however there are some experiments claimed to have successfully teleported "information" across a distance.

Comment: @HDE226868 massless stuff exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes!

... in a manner of speaking.

Quantum teleportation is [not what you think](https://xkcd.com/465/).  Wikipedia does a good job of describing it:

> [**Quantum teleportation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) is a process by which quantum information (e.g. the exact state of an atom or photon) can be transmitted (exactly, in principle) from one location to another, with the help of classical communication and previously shared quantum entanglement between the sending and receiving location.

This means that, unlike a Star Trek-type transporter, quantum teleportation does *not* mean that it is possible to "suck up" a quantum state at an arbitrary location and deposit it somewhere else.  Not only must the target and source "cooperate" in some sense by performing measurements on the entangled state, there must additionally be a classical transmission of information.

This means that there are two places in the process where energy is already transmitted!

- The initial distribution of the entangled state.
- The transmission of the classical information.

Note that there is a fundamental connection between matter, energy, and information ([as HDE 226868 mentioned](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28294/would-it-be-possible-to-teleport-energy#comment74321_28294)).  You can't send any information from one place to another without also sending some matter/energy to carry it.  So the answer to your question is threefold:

1. Quantum teleportation can (and indeed must) result in the transmission of energy.
2. However, quantum teleportation is *by definition* a transfer of quantum states, so a process which transmitted "energy *instead* of information" (emphasis mine) would not be quantum teleportation.
3. Additionally, our current understanding of physics does not permit<sup>1</sup> either matter *or* energy to go from one place to another without also going through the space in between.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> By this I do not mean, "we don't know how to do it yet," but instead "such a thing is *impossible* to the best of our knowledge."

<sup>2</sup> Wormholes don't violate this: when matter travels through a wormhole it still travels through space, it just takes a different route.

Answer (score 2):

So, think about how your teleportation mechanism functions.  Is it like a portal (as in the Portal games, Star Gate, or Rick and Morty?)  Portals are usually depicted as being capable of transferring energy.  Fast things with high kinetic energy tend to be moving equally fast when they come out the other side, kinetic energy is transferred.  Presumably chemical and thermal energy are also transferrable in this way.  (Hopefully: otherwise living matter when teleported would instantly starve and freeze upon emerging from the portal.)  The portal teleportation mechanism is depicted as simply linking two regions in space so that normally distant places can be moved between as if adjacent.

On the other hand, reassembly teleportation (as in Star Trek transporters) transfers a physical configuration from one place to another by breaking it down at point A and reassembling it at point B.  Though the episode writers don't always seem to grasp this point, teleporting chemical/nuclear, kinetic, and thermal energy in this manner is always a losing proposition: you'll have to input all the energy "teleported" at the point of reassembly, so you haven't really retrieved any from the point of origin.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to construct something besides a quantum device to do so.  For example, if your world's physics admits a wormhole which you can send stuff through, you'd be able to send energy through.  From a reality-check perspective, which on this forum usually implies a desire to use real-world knowledge to figure out if our fictional world is realistic, I'd have to say "nobody has ever found any way to make energy or mass travel between two points faster than the speed of light," with one caveat.  Topological constructs like wormholes may make it appear that something traveled faster than light, such as across the galaxy in a flash, but they are best modeled as having simply shortened the shortest distance between two points.  You could think of it as though you had a very long wall, and you usually have to walk all the way to the end in order to get to the other side.  Wormholes are like building a doorway in the wall.  They don't break the laws of physics, they just show you something that was always there.  (and there's some really frustrating limitations that do come up with the initial creation of them to make sure their construction doesn't break any laws, but once you have one, you're in great shape).

Quantum Mechanics can do a lot of really eerie things, but it actually can't teleport [classical] information.  There is a thing called quantum entanglement which allows the instantaneous transmission of quantum information, but it cannot transmit what you and I usually think of as information (classical information).  Entanglement can guarantee that two particles are in the same state, so if you observe particle A, its state will always be the same as particle B.  However there's a catch: you can't actually know what that state is, just that if someone else was observing it in that exact moment, they would see the same state.  You can't actually prove it either, without first sending the observations at the speed of light to the other party for comparison purposes. And, as a detail, observing the particle in a classical sense "collapses" the waveform, breaking the entanglement, so if you choose to observe such a particle classically, it becomes a one shot device.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by *teleportation*, if you assume in example that there's the need for a signal, then the signal itself could be the energy, and currently is an already existing technology (tramistting energy through micro-waves, laser or  light is already a current technology).

**Assume transfer would happens through entaglement:**

Assume you can make somehow 2 atoms entangled, so you can simply stimulate with energy one of those atoms and with a random chance of 1/2, one of the atoms emit a photon. You suddendly created a Entangled LED light, wich however has a power consumption which is twice of a normal LED (because you are actually lighting 2 LEDs).

I highly doubt entanglement works this way however, but since we are on world building.. (Entanglement can transmit only information, or that's the current knowledge)